# Storing multiple values in Keychain using Locksmith

Tags: swift, keychain

Can you store multiple key/value pairs under one `forUserAccount`?

```
try? Locksmith.saveData(["access_token" : access_token], forUserAccount: "UserData")
try? Locksmith.saveData(["email" : email!], forUserAccount: "UserData")
try? Locksmith.saveData(["markets" : market], forUserAccount: "UserData")
```

This code fails when looking for `"email."`. The only way I can do this is to create multiple `forUserAccount` strings: `UserData`, `UserData1`, `UserData3`, etc. I have tried `updateData` with no luck. If `forUserAccount` has to be unique, what is it for? It seems unnecessary if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let userIDNumber = userID as NSNumber
let userIDString : String = userIDNumber.stringValue
let keychainData = [_keychainEmailKey: email, _keychainPasswordKey: password, _keychainUserIDKey: userIDString]

Locksmith.updateData(keychainData, forUserAccount: email)
```

Where `_keychainEmailKey`, etc are constants for keys. So `forUserAccount` should be unique, probably it is overriding previous values.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @nyekimov's answer alludes to, a dictionary of values can be stored for an account. To clarify, here's a code snippet:

```
    do
    {
        try Locksmith.saveData(["user": "notMyRealUsername", "password":"123456"], forUserAccount: "myUserAccount") //store it
        let dictionary = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("myUserAccount") //load it 
        print(dictionary) //let's see what we've got
    } 
    catch 
    {
    // handle errors here    
    }
```

Use `try Locksmith.updateData(["user": "notMyRealUsernameEither", "password":"123456"], forUserAccount: "myUserAccount")` when an account exists.